# Updating complex array of objects in react

Tags: reactjs, state

I'm learning React and I'm trying to update nested array of objects but don't know how shall I achieve it. I tried various solutions from stackoverflow however, none were able to solve this thing. Please give me the solution which is without the use of hooks.

```
this.state ={
 index:0,
 array : [
      {
      "attribute": "value",
      "array1":
        [
          { "index": "0", "attribute1": "value1","attribute2": "value2","attribute3": "value3" },
          {  "index": "1","attribute1": "value1","attribute2": "value2","attribute3": "value3"  },
        ]
    },
    {
      "attribute": "value",
      "array2":
        [
          { "index": "0", "attribute1": "value1","attribute2": "value2","attribute3": "value3" },
          {  "index": "1","attribute1": "value1","attribute2": "value2","attribute3": "value3"  },
        ]
    },
  ]
}
```

```
handleChange = (event,position)=>{
   /*ideally this function should change the value of attribute1/2/3 in either of the array1 or array2.
Now to determine which array object is supposed to be change I'm storing a variable in state which is index and also passing the position value.*/
}
```

What I'm trying in the above function to achieve is if this.state.index = 0 and position = 1 then pickup the 1st object which is

```
{
      "attribute": "value",
      "array1":
        [
          { "index": "0", "attribute1": "value1","attribute2": "value2","attribute3": "value3" },
          {  "index": "1","attribute1": "value1","attribute2": "value2","attribute3": "value3"  },
        ]
    }
```

and from the position value change the value of

```
{  "index": "1","attribute1": "value1","attribute2": "value2","attribute3": "value3"  }
```

Moreover from event.target.value change the value of either of attribute1/2/3 values.

Thanks well in advance!

Comment: just reassign the property of the object in the array, it will set the state. Look at React documents about setting state and handling of objects in javascript

Comment: Hey Kenn, Will you please provide me the link.

Comment: Thanks @Kenn got it what were you trying to tell and it actually solved my query.